# If we know only the focus-directrix definition of the ellipse, then how can we say the ellipse is a closed curve?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Definition of the Ellipse: If $M$ is a fixed point (the *focus*) and $T$ is a fixed straight line (the *directrix*), and $P$ is a moving point which moves in a certain way to maintain the ratio $\frac {PM}{PN}= e$ (where $0<e<1$, and $PN$ is the perpendicular from $P$ to the directrix), then the locus of the $P$ will be called an *ellipse*.

> If we know only this definition of the ellipse, then how can we perceive the diagram of the ellipse? How can we say that the locus of the ellipse will be a closed curve?

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

We can check, for instance, if a ray issued from focus $M$ intersects the curve at a certain point $P$. Let $r$ be the distance $PM$, $a$ the distance from $M$ to the directrix $T$, $\theta$ the angle formed by ray $MP$ with the ray from $M$ perpendicular to $T$ but not intersecting $T$. The distance from $P$ to $T$ is then $r\cos\theta+a$and we have:
$$
{r\over r\cos\theta+a} = e,
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
r={ae\over1-e\cos\theta}.
$$
This gives a positive value of $r$ for any value of $\theta$, that is: every ray from the focus intersects the ellipse at a single point, distance $r$ is limited (${ae\over1+e}\le r\le{ae\over1+e}$) and $r(\theta)$ is a continuous function. It follows that the curve is closed.